# Instead of clicking, I want to open page with scrolls /new.php

Tags: javascript

This code opens `new.php` when I click an element on the page.

```js
$(document).ready(
    $("#2000").click(function() {
       $("#w36").load('/new.php');
    });
});
```

I would like to change its behavior, and instead of listening for a click, watch if the user scrolls a bit in the page.

How should I edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the scroll event :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        //do whatever you want
        $("#w36").load('/new.php');
        $(this).unbind("scroll");
    });
});
```

It works only if the scroll bar appears in your page.

Comment: Thank you ..
 how to increase the number of loads only once
Each time the page is scrolled continuously, /new.php is loaded

Comment: I mean, it only loads /new.php once
I do not want to load every time I scroll ... only the first time

Comment: Please embed in the above codes, I do not know much .. Thank you

Comment: @AmirSalar, Done.

Comment: Thanks, but it keeps loading

Comment: @AmirSalar, ok I see, try this solution again.

Comment: it just got fixed
Thank you very much, Professor

Comment: I have another question
Is it possible to write the same code with php?

Comment: php is a server side language, what's the issue ? why using php to catch scroll event ?

Comment: I do not know, it was just a question :)

Comment: Hello buddy
I have a question, can I give you a telegram?